# Returning a variable from external function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a .py file called foo.py, it has a function called "add", which code is below:

```
def Add(add1, add2)
addout = add1 + add2
return addout
```

When I call this via another file, bar.py and give it correct parameters, then try to print the "addout" variable in bar.py, it says it isnt defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the code that you are using to call this function?

Comment: `addout` won't be defined outside of scope of your function (`Add`). BTW. I suppose this is SO copy/paste/format issue, but the indentation is off.

Comment: The Code: add(1, 3)

Comment: Case sensitive is relevant so if you define "Add" function you must call "Add", not "add".

Comment: You don't return variables, you return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the Add function from foo.py

Try if this works:

foo.py:

```
def Add(add1, add2):
    addout = add1 + add2
    return addout
```

bar.py:

```
from foo import Add  # not sure if you need a file path before foo (Example: folder.foo)
# rest of the code

result = Add(AN_INTEGER, ANOTHER_INTEGER)
print(result)
```

Edit: You might want to use * instead of Add if you want to import the whole foo.py

Comment: "You might want to use * instead of Add if you want to import the whole foo.py" or just 'import foo'

Answer (score 0):

```
def Add(add1, add2)  # missing colon
addout = add1 + add2  # missing indentation
return addout  # missing indentation
```

Corrected:

```
def Add(add1, add2):
    addout = add1 + add2
    return addout
```